# Solve the error installation package is not supported by this processor type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installshield, outlook-addin

I am working to develop an add in for outlook 2010 with Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. To create the setup package I use InstallShield limited Edition.

The setup generated works on 64 bit pc.

It doesn't work on 32 bit systems. The reported error is:

> this installation package is not supported by this processor type

The test reporting the error has been done on a windows 7 32 bit.

The list of redistributables is:

- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 full
- Microsoft VSTO 2010 Runtime
- Visual studio 2010 Tools for Office runtime

I manually removed any register on 64 bit position.

Recompiling the solution in the log file I found this row:

> 2>Embedding file C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2013LE\Redist\Language Independent\x64\ISBEW64.exe into isregsvr.dll

Those are the informations used in the Compile area:

[image]

Can any one give me some information to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The error "this installation package is not supported by this processor type" indicates that the package is a 64-bit package. ISLE will create a 64-bit package when there are any files or registry being installed to 64-bit locations (as otherwise such items will not be installed correctly on 64-bit systems). Such items can also be included by merge modules, but I think ISLE generates an error for those unless the base package is already 64-bit.

So you have to find and modify or remove those items. You say you've already removed the registry items, so all you should have to find and remove are the files or folders somewhere under ProgramFiles64Folder, CommonFiles64Folder, or System64Folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, also with an Outlook Add-in. In my case, it was because I was writing a registry key under `SOFTWARE (64-Bit)/Microsoft/Office/Outlook`; after I removed this key, the installer worked on both 32 and 64 bit platforms, and the add-in also appeared to work normally on both platforms.