# How to explicit target an x86 environment with InstallShield LE for VS 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, windows-installer, installshield-le

Since the "default" Setup-Project-Type is now longer officially supported by Microsoft in VS 2015, i'm trying to deal with **InstallShield LE 2015** - delivered with VS2015.

I have created an Outlook AddIn, which i want to deploy on x86 AND x64 machines.
As far as i understand, **it's not possible with the Limited-Edition to create one single setup for both environments** - not really convinient, but OK for my needs.

So i have created an `InstallShieldProject` which runs on x64 environments as expected on my W10x64. 
But now i want to create a **x86 Setup**:
I have changed the `Platform target` for all Projects from `Any CPU` to `x86` and also created a **new Configuration** at the `Configuration Manager` to target x86 explicit.
But the resulting MSI (Setup) `doenst executes under an x86 environment:`
With the default "Platform not supported" message - on x64 everything works fine.

**Whow do i create a Setup for an x68 environment with InstallShield LE 2015?**

(The "Setup.exe"-Bootstrapper from IS-LE runs under x86, but not the containing MSI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a 32-bit package, you merely have to remove all items that are being installed into 64-bit file or registry locations. See also my [answer to this related but not quite duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35773158/89999) where I go into further detail.

Or my employer is willing to sell you a more powerful version of InstallShield that lets you specify a platform for your .msi file, but if this is your only reason to upgrade...

Comment: Thanks!! - I had one reg. defined for x64 in my IS-Project which causes the problem.